# Где ошибка при обработке АПИ?

Tags: php, api

Код

```
<?php
$cache_ttl = 21600; // время жизни кэша в секундах
$cache_file_airlines = "tmp/airlines.data";
$cache_file_products = "tmp/products.data";
$map = function ($array, $from, $to)
{
$result = [];
if (!empty($array) && is_array($array))
{
foreach ($array as $element)
{
$key = $element[$from] ? : null;
$value = $element[$to] ? : null;
if ($key && $value)
{
$result[$key] = $value;
}
}
}
return $result;
};
if (file_exists($cache_file_airlines) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_airlines)) < $cache_ttl)
{
// берём кэшированные данные
$get_airlines = file_get_contents($cache_file_airlines);
}
else
{
$get_airlines = file_get_contents('https://mysite.ru/json/airlines.json');
file_put_contents($cache_file_airlines, $get_airlines);
}
$airlines = array_column($data, 'name','iata');

if (file_exists($cache_file_products) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_products)) < $cache_ttl)
{
// берём кэшированные данные
$response = file_get_contents($cache_file_products);
}
else
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.ru/v3/prices_for_dates?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=5&token=****************");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"X-Access-Token: *********************"
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($cache_file_products, $response);
}
$products = json_decode($response, true);
$replace_value = function ($key, $val) use ($airlines)
{
$response = $val;
switch ($key)
{
case 'airline':
$response = $airlines[$val];
break;
}
return $response;
} ?>
 <div id="kurorty" class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div style="margin: 0px auto;padding: 10px;text-align: center;"><h2>Билеты Москва Адлер</h2>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align: center;">Направление</th>
<th class="mob" style="text-align: center;"></th><th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Дата вылета</th>
<th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Обратная дата</th>
<th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Цена</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td rowspan=6 id="Adler" style="height:356px;max-width: 370px;"><h3 class="gorod">Адлер</h3></td></tr>
<?php
if (isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data']))
{
foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data)
{
foreach ($data as $destination => $key)
{
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key))
{
?>
<tr>
<td class="mob"><img width="100" height="50" alt="авиакомпания на рейс Москва - Адлер" data-src="//pics.avs.io/100/40/<?=$data['airline'] ?>.jpg" class="lazyload air"/></td>
<td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('departure_at', substr($data['departure_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
<td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('return_at', substr($data['return_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
<td class="mob"> <?php echo $replace_value('price', $data['price']); ?> р. </td></tr>
<?php
}
}
}
}
?></tbody>
</table>
```

В этой части кода `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.ru/v3/prices_for_dates?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=5&token=****************");`

есть эндпоинт `&limit=5`, это значит в ответе давать 5 первых значений и если переходить по ссылке `https://site.ru/v3/prices_for_dates?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=5&token=****************` их будет действительно 5, но у меня после обработки появляются все значения. Вот сам ответ апи при переходе по ссылке, то-бишь до обработки

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AER","price":1450,"airline":"5N","flight_number":"243","departure_at":"2021-09-28T05:25:00+03:00","search_id":"051a2017-af93-40df-808d-93e22d548fe4","signature":"2ea6cb4921c192001f79124cae747069","transfers":0,"return_transfers":0},{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AER","price":1462,"airline":"RL","flight_number":"707","departure_at":"2021-10-15T07:00:00+03:00","search_id":"4ed2f7da-b4c4-4eb7-8f56-80c28f761072","signature":"c38a5f7135922f5cfc6d9b9dc27bd13c","transfers":0,"return_transfers":0},{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AER","price":1462,"airline":"RL","flight_number":"707","departure_at":"2021-10-17T07:00:00+03:00","search_id":"542477cd-abab-45c6-abef-7a930006ce4a","signature":"0d812014380b23a5554889c0315b01af","transfers":0,"return_transfers":0},{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AER","price":1477,"airline":"RL","flight_number":"707","departure_at":"2021-10-14T07:00:00+03:00","search_id":"06ad509a-3c07-4523-b49e-9ab098a20bb1","signature":"59f72f531377cecd03d3bf113e3f4cae","transfers":0,"return_transfers":0},{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AER","price":1499,"airline":"N4","flight_number":"225","departure_at":"2021-11-10T16:35:00+03:00","search_id":"96daee03-3a5a-4bfd-b6d5-396f2d4fc441","signature":"69766e5c228b24327112399d7de36d25","transfers":0,"return_transfers":0}],"currency":"rub"}
```

Вопрос где ошибка? Спасибо

Comment: тут 5 значений. в чём прикол?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если по ссылкея перейду вижу их 5, а после обработки АПИ у меня не работает этот эндпоинт, показываются значения больше пяти

Comment: @АлексейШиманский до обработки АПИ, после мой обработки их гораздо больше, то-бишь где-то ошибка у меня в коде.

Comment: "но у меня после обработки" --- после какой обработки?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы здесь?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "после какой обработки?" - кода пытаюсь вывести данные